# angular routeProvider not finding template url

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

Hi so I have something set up like this:

```
$routeProvider.when('/login', {
           templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',  
           controller:'queriesController',
        })
        .when('/', {
                templateUrl:'partials/tables.html',
                controller:'queriesController',
                resolve: {
                    environments: function (RefDataService) {
                        return RefDataService.getEnvironments();
                    }
                }
            })
            .when('/transactions', {
                templateUrl:'partials/transactions.html',
                controller:'transactionsController'
            })
            .otherwise({redirect:"/"});
```

but when I ping my link:

```
http://localhost:8080/blah/#/login
```

I just get taken to my other url page. In this instance it would be the tables.html. Is there a reason why it might not be picking up the /login or not using my templateUrl. If it matters this is a tomcat app and It was working before I added the new /login when.

Comment: Try this /#//login and you will see login.html. Please read [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider)

Comment: @DavidDennis thanks for fixing the tags. Now I'll say that you should should consider using ui-router ;)

Comment: @SiderTopalov  /#//login hits my otherwise so it redirects to /. Now sure why I would need // ?!

Comment: @AluanHaddad I've looked into but my past projects use ng-router. So I figured id stick with it. Not sure why it's being weird in this case.

Comment: @DavidDennis remove the extra slash and you should be taken to login `/#/login`

Comment: Okay then the try to use template instead of templateUrl. Also do you have ng-view in your html page?

Comment: @SiderTopalov if the template can't be resolved by URL wouldn't it throw an error?

Comment: @AluanHaddad that's correct which I do not get. It's some config thing. Just figured i'd post incase someone had the same issue before.

Comment: There is a few cases but i can’t figure out without see more from your code. Problems can be there 1. You are missing ng-view in your main html, 2. Problem can come from this .when('/'...) 3. Problem can be in your path for template. Also can you try to hit other urls and see what’s happening?

Comment: Here is what I would do to start debugging.  Change your `otherwise` to `/login` and then type in an invalid route and see what happens.  Either it will show you the correct URL or it should expose another problem.

Comment: Bro i think i saw your problem please remove "," after queriesController in /login

Comment: @SiderTopalov while that was a problem it did not fix my initial problem. I'm debugging and will post a solution if I find one.